# nginx rule for specific php file

Tags: nginx, php

I use nginx with modsecurity and php-fpm on my web server.

I use OWASP ModSecurity Core Rule Set.

I'm trying to use some specific rules for one php file (contact.php)

Here is my nginx config:

```
        location /contact.php {
            ModSecurityEnabled on;
            ModSecurityConfig ../owasp-modsecurity-crs/modsecurity_rule1.conf; # Specific rules for this file
    }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            root /home/user/public_html;
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
            ModSecurityEnabled on;
            ModSecurityConfig ../owasp-modsecurity-crs/modsecurity.conf;
    }
```

When I run with this config I get "500 Internal Server Error"

And this error in the php-fpm 's error.log file:

```
2015/01/28 05:43:01 [alert] 1395#0: *1 no upstream configuration, client: IPAdress, server: example.com, request: "POST /contact.php HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/"
```

I guess there is a confusion with the two "location" blocks.

How to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

location /contact.php has no upstream configured. You must copy-paste all remaining directives from second location

or if you want to keep it DRY maybe this will work:

```
http {
map $request_uri $mod_sec_config {
    /contact.php modsecurity_rule1.conf;
    default      modsecurity.conf;
}
}
.....
        location ~ \.php$ {
            root /home/user/public_html;
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
            ModSecurityEnabled on;
            ModSecurityConfig ../owasp-modsecurity-crs/$mod_seq_config;
    }
```

Not sure if this will work though, and according to nginx authors copy-paste is the right way of writing configs

Comment: I copied-pasted remaining directives to location /contact.php block but it doesn't work. Getting the same error. I tried to run with your config but doesn't work

Comment: so you have fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001; in /contact.php configuration now? then "no upstream configuration" error have no sence. Did you reload nginx after changing config?

Comment: Yes I have fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001; in location /contact.php Yes I reloaded nginx but still getting the same error.